# In EF Core Migration when setting Cascade Delete does it not enforce it in the database?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Why when setting Cascade delete between Parent and Child entity does it not create the Cascade in the migration?

Usual Blog / Post example:

```
class Blog
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public IList<Post> Posts { get;set;}
}

class Post
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public Blog Blog { get;set;}
}
```

In the EntityTypeConfiguration file

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Notification> builder)
    {
 
        builder.HasMany(n => n.Posts).WithOne(e => e.Blog)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```

Why does it create the migration script of?

```
            ...
            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Posts_Blogs_BlogId",
            table: "Posts",
            column: "BlogId",
            principalTable: "Blogs",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            ...
```

Note the

> **onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict**

I understand that EF will actually do the cascade delete internally as long as you include the child objects for it to work through but why not leverage the Database Services cascade delete to be able to delete it in one command rather than 1 + n SQL commands
i.e. 1 x Blog record & n x posts.

Imagine that there are 1000s of posts and you are deleting a blog.

Comment: Are you sure you entity type configuration is being applied? I've used `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` extensively, and it's always produced `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade` for me.

Comment: Mind you, I tend to configure the relationship from the "many" end instead: `builder.HasOne(p => p.Blog).WithMany(b => b.Posts).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);` - I'm not sure whether that would make a difference.

Comment: I've just tried both ways and I get the same result. Using EF Core 6.0.0

Comment: I have also altered the migration to cascade and it works as expected but that doesn't answer why it didn't do that with the add-migration command

Comment: Just tried those classes and configuration in a new .NET 6 console app with EF Core 6.0.1, and it produced `ReferentialAction.Cascade` as expected. After trying several different approaches, I couldn't get it to generate `ReferentialAction.Restrict` at all.

Comment: Updated to v 6.0.1 and just tried again and still same

Comment: There must be something else going on with your test project. [Here's a Gist with my test project](https://gist.github.com/RichardD2/7f82441c3bd2c2667b21f84e197d6cfc), in case you can spot any differences.

Comment: There must be something up in the project. Just copied this in to our project and got the same result. Confused :) 

Just tried it in an new empty project and it worked.
Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the project which I was trying to do this in a realised that the Dbcontext was inherited from a base class  which had this code in...

```
private void ConfigureEntities(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);

        var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .ToList();

        // Disable cascade delete
        var foreignKeys = entityTypes
            .SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys().Where(f => f.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade));
        foreach (var foreignKey in foreignKeys)
        {
            foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
    }
```

In the end I copied this into the Gist Project and replicated it straight away.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(TestContext).Assembly);

        var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .ToList();
        var foreignKeys = entityTypes
        .SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys().Where(f => f.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade));
        foreach (var foreignKey in foreignKeys)
        {
            foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure why this was done but plan to find out, I think it came from a previous Template that we were using.